# Android: How to check why an app is "Not Compatible"

Tags: android, api, incompatibility

My app is targeting API/minSDKversion 5 and runs fine on 2.2. My friend just tried to download my app onto his Samsung Galaxy S2 running 2.3.4 but was met with the "not compatible" warning. Is there some way I can see why my app is not compatible?

Answer (score 2):

The same problem I have resolved using `<supports-screen>` and `<compatible-screen>` tags in AndroidManifest.xml, also sometimes it make sense to check tag

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true"/>
```

since some tablets don't have telephony

Answer (score 0):

Check this , this will help you to solve your problem. [Market Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html)

Comment: please don't post direct links as an answer. Either explain specifically what part is interesting or add it as a comment